# Обработка checkbox в PHP

Tags: checkbox, php, html

Доброго времени суток!

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с моей проблемой.

Есть 2 страницы: `html` (1-я) и `php` (2-я). На первой странице есть чекбоксы в форме, значения которых передаются во вторую и принимаются методом `$_REQUEST`. На php-странице тоже есть чекбоксы и нужно, чтобы они отмечались в зависимости от значений чекбоксов с html-страницы. Как это реализовать?

Не ругайте, пожалуйста, сильно за оформление вопроса, если что не так, это мой первый вопрос здесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужна на второй странице примерно такая  конструкция -

```
echo "<input type='checkbox'";
if($_REQUEST['name вашего checkbox']){
 echo " checked ";
}
echo " />";
```

Если остались еще вопросы - покажите ваш код

Comment: Спасибо большое, это то что нужно))